# Gradle Kotlin DSL: subdirectory for javadoc in jar file

Tags: java, gradle, jar, javadoc, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I currently have the following configuration in my build.gradle.kts:

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Multi-Release"] = "true"
    }
    from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
    from(sourceSets["test"].allSource)
    from(tasks["javadoc"])
}
```

When I run the jar task, the generated javadoc html files are included in the exported jar. However, I want to include the javadoc in a subdirectory called "javadoc". How can I achieve this, i.e. change the output location of the generated javadoc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just solved this as follows:

```
tasks.withType<Jar> {
    manifest {
        attributes["Multi-Release"] = "true"
    }
    from(sourceSets["main"].allSource)
    from(sourceSets["test"].allSource)
    {
        from(tasks["javadoc"]).into("/javadoc")
    }

}
```